# Is there a way to control smoothing groups in blender?

Tags: modeling, export, normals, .fbx

I'm trying to export a model from Blender to FBX format I'm using auto smooth with weighted normal modifier set to 50, and for some reason, I'm not sure why when my client inspect the model in 3ds he gets two different smoothing group, now according to this answer

> Blender doesn't have a concept of Smoothing groups like 3ds max, here you define sharp edges, but they should be kept intact when exported to 3ds. Material IDs are called material slots, and should also be exported faithfully by default – Duarte Farrajota Ramos

I only need one smooth group when inspecting the model in 3ds is there a way to control this in blender?